# How should I compute an hashValue?

Tags: swift, hash

I saw several examples of implementations of the `Hashable` variable `hashValue`, such as these:

```
extension Country: Hashable {
  var hashValue: Int {
    return name.hashValue ^ capital.hashValue ^ visited.hashValue
  }
}


var hashValue: Int {
    return self.scalarArray.reduce(5381) {
        ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ Int($1)
    }
}


var hashValue : Int {
    get {
        return String(self.scalarArray.map { UnicodeScalar($0) }).hashValue
    }
}
```

and so on.
In some cases `OR`, `XOR` or `BITWISE` operators are used. In other cases, other algorithms, map or filter functions etc.

Now I'm a bit confused. What is the rule of thumb to compute a good hashValue?

In the simplest case with two string variables, should I combine these two with an OR operator?

Comment: Your first one looks perfect. But you should make your Country also conform to Equatable protocol and if needed to Comparable protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus I believe they are all correct. I took all these examples from tutorials. But I could not find why should I use one rather than another one. For example in some cases, << bitwise operator was used on string hash values. When should I use it?

Comment: The really important think is to provide the Equatable protocol correctly. The hashValue without collisions would be really complex task

Comment: @LeoDabus So what you are saying is that I can just use OR operators, and this is good enough. The other methods improve the hashing to better avoid collision, but that's more advanced optimization I don't need unless performance is important. Correct?

Comment: Simple hash functions are fast, but produce more collisions. For example, the XOR hash is invariant under permutations of the variables. More sophisticated hash functions produce less collisions, but are slower to compute. It's up to you to decide between the two goals.

Comment: I don’t know if the others are better than your first one. But yes as long as your Equatable it is implemented correctly you are good to go

Comment: @MartinR Perfect. Got it.

Comment: I wonder if it is pure coincidence that the second hash function looks like the one in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111573/35991 :)

Comment: @MartinR  I saw that post, but I copy pasted the snippet from a website :) It was the same, just google for it

Comment: Of course it always depends on the properties (type and range) that you want to hash: integers (in a small or large range), floating point numbers, strings, ... There is no "one fits all" solution. – Here is an example which shows the effect of different hash functions: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/148763/35991.

Comment: *In the simplest case with two string variables, should I combine these two with an OR operator?* You could get the `hashValue` of the concatenated strings: `(str1 + str2).hashValue`.

Comment: @vacawama considering that there are no countries with the same name I would just use  `name.hashValue`

Comment: @LeoDabus, that's a good point.  I was answering that question for the general case, but yes, considering the context can yield a more clever solution.

Comment: @LeoDabus Only considering the `name` might be wrong: This specific `Country` type does not simply specify existing (immutable) countries. It has a `visited` property which suggests there can be differing instances (like for different visitors). It could also store epochs of the country (like Germany of the 80s when Bonn was the capital while it's now Berlin). In short: The fact that the type *stores* these properties makes them an inherent part of its value. That's exactly how Swift's upcoming automatic `Hashable` will decide which properties to add to the `hashValue`.

Answer (score 0):

From Swift 4.2, you can use [Hasher](https://nshipster.com/hashable/)

> Swift 4.2 implements hashing based on the SipHash family of
>   pseudorandom functions, specifically SipHash-1-3 and SipHash-2-4, with
>   1 or 2 rounds of hashing per message block and 3 or 4 rounds of
>   finalization, respectively.
>
> Now if you want to customize how your type implements Hashable, you
>   can override the hash(into:) method instead of hashValue. The
>   hash(into:) method passes a Hasher object by reference, which you call
>   combine(_:) on to add the essential state information of your type.

```
// Swift >= 4.2
struct Color: Hashable {
    let red: UInt8
    let green: UInt8
    let blue: UInt8

    // Synthesized by compiler
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.red)
        hasher.combine(self.green)
        hasher.combine(self.blue)
    }

    // Default implementation from protocol extension
    var hashValue: Int {
        var hasher = Hasher()
        self.hash(into: &hasher)
        return hasher.finalize()
    }
}
```